# Many-to-many relationship in factory_boy?

Tags: unit-testing, django-testing, factory-boy

I'm trying to test a many-to-many relationship between two Django models using factory_boy.  The factory_boy documentation doesn't appear to discuss this and I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong.  When I run the first test, I get the error "AttributeError: 'Pizza' object has no attribute 'topping'".  I get a similar error for the second test.

When I run the tests in the debugger, I can see a 'toppings' object but it don't understand how to get the name from it.  Have I defined PizzaFactory's _prepare method properly?  How do you access the name in one table from the other table when you have a many-to-many relationship?

Thanks.

### models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

### factories.py:

```
import factory
from models import Topping, Pizza

class ToppingFactory(factory.Factory):
    name = 'mushrooms'

class PizzaFactory(factory.Factory):
    name = 'Vegetarian'

    @classmethod
    def _prepare(cls, create, **kwargs):
        topping = ToppingFactory()
        pizza = super(PizzaFactory, cls)._prepare(create, **kwargs)
        pizza.toppings.add(topping)
        return pizza
```

### tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
import factory
from app.models import Topping, Pizza
from app.factories import ToppingFactory, PizzaFactory

class FactoryTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_pizza_has_mushrooms(self):
        pizza = PizzaFactory()
        self.assertTrue(pizza.topping.name, 'mushrooms')

    def test_mushrooms_on_pizza(self):
        topping = ToppingFactory()
        self.assertTrue(topping.pizza.name, 'Vegetarian')
```

Answer (score 37):

I believe you need to use the `@factory.post_generation` decorator:

```
class PizzaFactory(factory.Factory):
    name = 'Vegetarian'

    @factory.post_generation
    def toppings(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of groups were passed in, use them
            for topping in extracted:
                self.toppings.add(topping)
```

Then you would call it in tests.py `pizza = PizzaFactory.create(toppings=(topping1, topping2, topping3))`

This is taken directly from https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html.

Answer (score 7):

Just use mixer instead:

```
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

# Generate toppings randomly
pizza = mixer.blend(Pizza, toppings=mixer.RANDOM)

# Set toppings
toppings = mixer.cycle(3).blend(Topping)
pizza = mixer.blend(Pizza, toppings=toppings)

# Generate toppings with name=tomato
pizze = mixer.blend(Pizza, toppings__name='tomato')
```

Easy, configurable, faster, schemaless, declarative and you are getting in some tests what you want.

Comment: Supporting anecdote -- why I chose `mixer`... I was drawn to `factory_boy` initially. I liked how in `factory_boy`, for a given `Factory` you could call a method `attributes()` and get a `dict` back, good for use with **[`dataset`](http://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)**. But what's great about `mixer` is it helps you be DRY because of how it can do so much on-the-fly. That means less testing-code to change if your code-under-test changes in the future!

Comment: are you guys still supporting it?

Comment: Last commit for mixer was in in march, 2022... RIP